# Python requests accessing index of response object

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to practice aggregating data from an api call

i have this script

```
r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')

print r.text
```

which returns an array of objects in this format

```
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
   }]
```

I've been playing around and tried this to see if I can access the first object

```
print r.text[0]
```

And it didn't work. So how do I do this with python

Comment: Did `print r.text[0]` return anything? (A space? a bracket?)

Comment: It's not returnning an array, it's returning a JSON string. You need to use `json.loads()` to parse it into an array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the JSON text:

```
import json
array = json.loads(r)
print array[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

request.text returns Http response body. 
so If you want to get first propery of json,
you should convert string to json object.

**This works**

```
result = r.text
print(type) # prints str

import json
result = json.loads(result)

print(result[0]) # (...)
```